# .NET, Entity Framework: objects removal - which is faster/better?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, compare

Sometimes I have to face removing many rows at one time. It costs large amount of time (for example removing 3000 elements + ~21000 related elements costs me approx. 4 minutes).

The way I do it:

```
// removes settlement elements
var settlementElements = context.SettlementElements.Where(x => x.SettlementElementSettlementId == id);                     context.SettlementElements.RemoveRange(settlementElements);
```

I wonder if getting only IDs of those elements, create empty objects with those IDs, attach them and remove would be faster than remove range used above? I mean sth like this:

```
var settlementElementsIds = context.SettlementElements.Where(x => x.SettlementElementSettlementId == id).Select(x => x.SettlementElementId);
foreach (var seID in settlementElementsIds)
{
    var obj = new SettlementElements() { SettlementElementId = seID };
    context.SettlementElements.Attach(obj);
    context.SettlementElements.Remove(obj);
}
```

Do you have some experience in optimizing elements removal?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

If you want proper bulk delete functionality, use EFPlus package: http://entityframework-plus.net/

**Details**

As @Tom Lawrence wrote, using `RemoveRange` would improve the performance of the in-memory loop. Yet the code above will cause retrieval of the records into memory, and then EF will generate separate `DELETE` statement per each record being deleted, as shown in the example below:

```cs
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
var id = 111;
var settlementElements = context.SettlementElements
    .Where(x => x.SettlementElementSettlementId == id);
context.SettlementElements.RemoveRange(settlementElements);
context.SaveChanges();
```

would produce this output, assuming there are 3 records to delete from settlement ID=111:

```sql
Opened connection at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
SELECT
    [Extent1].[SettlementElementId] AS [SettlementElementId],
    [Extent1].[SettlementElementSettlementId] AS [SettlementElementSettlementId],
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[SettlementElements] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[SettlementElementSettlementId] = @p__linq__0
-- p__linq__0: '111' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
-- Completed in 5 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
Opened connection at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
Started transaction at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
DELETE [dbo].[SettlementElements]
WHERE ([SettlementElementId] = @0)
-- @0: '1111' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
-- Completed in 1 ms with result: 1

DELETE [dbo].[SettlementElements]
WHERE ([SettlementElementId] = @0)
-- @0: '1112' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: 1

DELETE [dbo].[SettlementElements]
WHERE ([SettlementElementId] = @0)
-- @0: '1113' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: 1

Committed transaction at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
Closed connection at 10/25/2017 2:08:33 PM +03:00
```

**This is definitely not an option if we have millions of records to delete!**

With EFPlus, the following code:

```cs
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

// ...

context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
var id = 111;
var settlementElements = context.SettlementElements
    .Where(x => x.SettlementElementSettlementId == id);
settlementElements.Delete(); // <-- proper bulk delete method
context.SaveChanges();
```

will produce this output for the same example data:

```sql
Opened connection at 10/25/2017 2:20:29 PM +03:00

DECLARE @rowAffected INT
DECLARE @totalRowAffected INT

SET @totalRowAffected = 0

WHILE @rowAffected IS NULL
    OR @rowAffected > 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (4000)
        FROM    A
        FROM    [dbo].[SettlementElements] AS A
                INNER JOIN ( SELECT
    [Extent1].[SettlementElementId] AS [SettlementElementId]
    FROM [dbo].[SettlementElements] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[SettlementElementSettlementId] = @p__linq__0
                           ) AS B ON A.[SettlementElementId] = B.[SettlementElementId]

        SET @rowAffected = @@ROWCOUNT
        SET @totalRowAffected = @totalRowAffected + @rowAffected
    END

SELECT  @totalRowAffected
-- p__linq__0: '111' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 10/25/2017 2:20:29 PM +03:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: 3

Closed connection at 10/25/2017 2:20:29 PM +03:00
```

We can see that:

- the `SELECT` statement is gone; there is no fetch into memory
- there is single `DELETE` statement, and not one per record

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have had to do any form of bulk processing, I have found speed improvements by doing it in a stored procedure. You could run a quick test by creating a delete and compare, I can help with that if a stored procedure is an option for you.

You could also try using RemoveRange instead of a stored procedure if available in your version (ef6)

```
db.SettleElements.RemoveRange(itemstodelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The docs say RemoveRange may perform significantly better than calling Remove multiple times would do.

Source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: What about a cascade in DB? Can it speed up too?

Answer (score 0):

As @felix-b answered,

The fastest way if you can use it, is using my free library [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/) + `BatchDelete`.

Another technic, if you already have all entities you want to delete is using `BulkDelete`.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to perform all bulk operations including BulkDelete required by your application:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```